# Msql getting incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

i am using mysql version 5.7.13 in linux

When i running the stored procedure i am getting the following error

```
ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause 
and contains nonaggregated column 'medigurus.pp.physicianid' which is not
   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is  
 incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

My Procedure is

```
 DELIMITER $$ DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS medigurus.getPatientDoctors$$ CREATE 
 DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE getPatientDoctors(IN patientid INT(10)) 
 BEGIN SELECT pp.physicianid, d.physiciantypeid, p.firstname, p.lastname, 
 p.dob, p.mobile, p.officephone, p.address1, p.address2, p.city, p.stateid, 
 p.cid, p.zip,p.speciality, p.about, p.imgid FROM patientphysicians pp INNER 
 JOIN physician p ON pp.physicianid = p.physicianid INNER JOIN 
  getpatientdoctorsview AS d ON d.patientid=pp.patientid WHERE pp.patientid 
      = patientid GROUP BY p.physicianid; END$$ DELIMITER ;
```

and view is

```
    DELIMITER $$

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `medigurus`.`getpatientdoctorsview`$$

 CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED 
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `getpatientdoctorsview`    AS
  select `pp`.`physicianid` AS `physicianid`,`pp`.`patientid` AS 
`patientid`,group_concat(`pp`.`physiciantypeid` separator ',') AS  
 `physiciantypeid`
   from `patientphysicians` `pp` group by `pp`.`patientid`$$

   DELIMITER ;
```

How can i fix the error..

Comment: Would you accept the helpful answer below, arjun, as per the request in the comments? Ping me when you do so, and I will undownvote the question.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution is to apply an aggregate function to `medigurus.pp.physicianid`, like this:

```
select ...  min(medigurus.pp.physicianid) as physicianid, ...
```

The reason for the error message is that `medigurus.pp.physicianid` is ambiguous as there could be several values per group, and the SQL engine would need to pick one. Without this setting (restriction), it would just take the first one it encounters, but that behaviour is not in line with the SQL standards.

However, by indicating which one of these values you want to return (e.g. via `min`), you resolve the issue.

#### Disabling the "only full group by" option

Alternatively, although not advised, you can return to the old behaviour of MySql, by clearing this option:

```
SET sql_mode = ''
```

#### Concerning the procedure and view

As you provided the actual SQL you have in an update of your question, I add here my observation on that:

The view's `select` groups the result by *patientid* in order to aggregate the types of the associated physicians. However, you also select the *physicianid*: this makes little sense, as in general you might have several different physicians associated with one patient, so its value is not singular. You should just omit that field -- or if you really need one physician per patient, you should ask yourself the question: which one, if there is more than one? Here I will suggest to omit it:

```
select   patientid AS patientid,
         group_concat(physiciantypeid separator ',') AS physiciantypeid
from     patientphysicians
group by patientid
```

Secondly, the procedure's SQL is also in need of correction. You seem to want to list the details of all the physicians associated with one particular patient. For that purpose it makes no sense to join the view, as the view only returns one record for a patient, and aggregates the physician types into a comma separated list. This is not useful for the SQL you have in the procedure, where you want a separate record for each physician. So remove the view from it, and just return the physician type for each physician.

Apart from that, you should group by the same *physicianid* as the one you have in the `select` list. Don't select the *physicianid* from *pp* in the `select` clause and group by the *physicianid* from *p*.

Here is the suggested update:

```
SELECT     p.physicianid,
           p.physiciantypeid,
           p.firstname,
           p.lastname,
           p.dob,
           p.mobile,
           p.officephone,
           p.address1,
           p.address2,
           p.city,
           p.stateid,
           p.cid,
           p.zip,
           p.speciality,
           p.about,
           p.imgid
FROM       patientphysicians pp
INNER JOIN physician p 
        ON pp.physicianid = p.physicianid
WHERE      pp.patientid = patientid /* the argument */
GROUP BY   p.physicianid
```

Note that it really helps to understand code better when you apply proper indentation.

Comment: i am new to mysql,here i am sharing the procedure and view can you please see once.

Comment: But looking at it, I wonder why your first field in the select list has `pp` as prefix and not just `p`: that would already resolve it.

Comment: i set the sql_mode = '',still getting the same error.

Comment: I checked it. See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Did this answer your question? Could you accept the answer if it did?